# Using or Through?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Egyptians teach Islamic teachings and beliefs  **using / through**  the Arabic language curriculum.

Comment: Is it a *method* of teaching? If so, then I'd say it should be *(by) using*. To teach, you  *use* a blackboard, a projector, or the Socratic method. But if it doesn't have to be one or the other, I'd say the sentence should use *with*.

Comment: Why close vote?

Comment: Jason you say I should say "Egyptians **use** the Arabic language curriculum **to teach** Islamic teachings and beliefs " or  "Egyptians teach Islamic teachings and beliefs **by using** The arabic language curriculum". I think you are right. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If it is part of the curriculum, then it is *through*; if not then it can only be *using*.

Comment: unfortunately, It is part of the curriculum,  Kris. And I am fighting to remove It.

Comment: That should not matter as far as grammar/ meaning/ usage is concerned.